# Give an infinite sequence of principal ideals of $R$ such that the ascending chain condition does not hold

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, ring-theory, ideals

Let $R=\{\sum_{i=0}^n a_ix^i\mid n\geq 0, a_0\in\mathbb{Z}, a_i\in\mathbb{Q}  \text{  for } i\geq 1\}$. Give an infinite sequence of principal ideals of $R$ such that the ascending chain condition does not hold:

$I_1<I_2<\cdots$, where $I_1,I_2,\cdots$ are principal ideals of $R$.

Comment: Hint: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ascending_chain_condition_for_principal_ideals

Comment: Well. You should know that without the restriction on $a_0$ you would have a PID. Is that not a sufficient clue as to what to try? Sorry, if this is a bit crude, but you can't expect to pass a grad level exam by memorizing all the possible counterexamples. You also need to learn ways of thinking that help you construct them. Admittedly I have forgotten most of the counter examples related to separation axioms from point-set topology. I would need to spend quite some time reviewing Munkres to reach that point. Good luck!!

Comment: @vadim123 : That is not a hint - your link contains the answer!